# SSL is not enabled in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, heroku

Since Heroku has integrated the `piggybank_ssl` addon by default, trying:

```
heroku addons:add piggyback_ssl
```

or

```
heroku addons:add ssl:piggyback
```

results in:

> !    This add-on is now a standard Heroku platform feature. !    Your
>   apps can already use piggyback SSL.

But, accessing: `mywebsite.herokuapp.com` results in:

> SSL is not enabled mywebsite.herokuapp.com does not have SSL enabled.

My `production.rb` has:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

I have read the page SSL on Heroku, but it's obsolete, they suggest to run:

```
heroku addons:add piggyback_ssl
```

Which is no longer necessary.

SOLVED !

I didn't change anything, and now it's working. It seems that it was a heroku problem.

Comment: @Drom: Have you reviewed the help page for [SSL on Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl)?

Comment: @ Drom: If the question is solved, please post that as the answer so the question is not left unanswered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a place holder answer until the original poster post an answer stating that after posting the issue that SSL became enabled in Heroku without any know change on their part, and that the issue appears to be a result of some issue on Heroku's end since nothing was change, but the issue went away. See the last update at the bottom of the original poster's question for additional information.